# Interview Question: Maximize Points Against An Opponent By Predicting a Longest Route in a Binary Tree

Tags: logic, binary-tree, graph-traversal

I was hit with this interview question today and was totally stumped.
Suppose there's a game that takes the form of a binary tree where each node has a unique value and up to three pointers pointing at a parent and 0, 1, or 2 children. An opponent picks a node to begin from and, once you pick your starting node, the two of you will pick paths simultaneously to follow and add the node it leads to to each of your domains. You may pick any path from the nodes in your current domain leading to nodes not yet added to your domain OR your opponent's. In other words, any nodes claimed by you or or opponent are off limits to both of you, meaning no returning paths to nodes you've already claimed and you and your opponent may effectively block each other off from branches by claiming nodes that make the branch otherwise untraversable.

The goal is to maximize the number of nodes in your domain, each of which are worth one point, and win the game if possible. You have access to the root node of the tree and the node your opponent chose as their starting place as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand the rules of the game correctly, it sounds like I would just compare the maximum heights of the sub-trees surrounding your opponent's starting node. Since it's a binary tree, there are at most 3 possible sub trees (parent and 2 children) you need to look at. After you choose your node, just follow the path with the most nodes.